# Что такое "сусала"?

Tags: этимология

Помните совет профессора Выбегалло: "А кусаться он начнет, так ты его по сусалам, не стесняйся. Се ля ви"? Так вот, интересно, а что такое эти самые сусала и как они связаны с сусальным золотом?

Answer (score 6):

Сусала - это лицо, скулы. Сусальное золото - золото, раскатанное до толщины в несколько микрон, которое используется для украшения лицевой стороны чего-либо. Насколько достоверно - не знаю. Смущает, что вполне благостное слово "сусальное" образовано от просторечного слова. Более того, от диалектного, если верить словарю Ушакова.

Answer (score 4):

Насчет этимологии. Для начала: не просторечное относительно современное "сусала", а вполне себе литературное, но древнерусское "сусало" - лицо, скулы. Просторечный же вариант связан с переносом значения исключительно на скулы, которых, как известно - две. Отсюда и множественное.
А происхождение (вернее сказать - объяснение) вместе с тем действительно спорно. Есть подозрение, что "сусалом" называлась не просто "лицевая, противоположная задней или изнаночной, часть" чего-либо, а "лицо" в переносном значении - то на что обращают внимание, как сейчас "лицо фирмы", "лицо города". И вот этим-то "лицом" и было сусальное золото. Т.е., примерно, это золото не просто украшение чьего-то "лица", оно само по себе - лицо. Это небольшое уточнение выглядит вполне правдоподобным и продуктивным объяснением.

Я сейчас не вдаюсь в подробности, насколько близки и связаны два упомянутых переносных значения "лица", но даже этот маленький оттенок смысла тянет на самостоятельную версию. Беда только, что ничем кроме моих рассуждений подтвердить не могу.

Comment: А еще гидроним есть  сысола., и усолья всякие.Пермяцкий край и соль. Так сколько бы вы минусов не ставили, но золото от соли,. и сало тоже, и слон, не прислонялся , а солонина. А у Фасмера, с таким успехом бездумно цитиреумого, сало от седла, где сала в принципе не бывает. с седла мясо имееют, и никто на нем , на мясе, не сидит, только фантасты историки с лингвистами, помешанные на отбивной от заднего места татаро-монгол придуманных. А что нашим-хорошо, то на западе-смерть, бляшки в аорту. А ваш любимый Фасмер с запада этимологию тянул, НЕ наш это человек! Это на соли сидели. Сели и село.

Comment: Кстати--скула это не морда, не харя, и не лицо тем более, а опухоль,Прыщь. Скулят - это соленые слезы по сусалам. Так что деваться некуда. Бьют именно туда, где выпукло,  под глаз, ниже которого сало и висит, у кого не лицо, а морда погана, типа в прыщах. И это по сусалвм, гораздо обиднее, чем просто по морде.

А демонстрация золота, это реклама,когда его много, выпендреж, а не лицо.
Хоть с какой стороны не смотри.
а про сусло, уже сказал. Там еще связочка имемется--это от его цвета--от светло  до темно желтого. а еще и жирно-густое. а еще -оба с сусальным -полуфабрикаты..

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то там явно присутствует слово сало, а приставка су(соу) это соединяюще-объединяющая в значении  начиная от пары и больше-много. В современном виде это еще приставка СО.
Бить по сусалам--это по сальной блестящей толстой морде, где на щеках висит сало.
Лицо в русском языке и так есть. А это эпитет. Читая иностранца Фасмера многогранности русского языка не прочувствуешь.

CУСАЛО->Сысала  шедеврально! шипит. Скорее это СУСЛО--шипит, когда пиво бродит.И пробовать можно суслить, сусолить, сосать медленно. . А от шипения суслик. Мусолить несколько другое, это пальцами тереть, соль мучать.Что интересно и деньги и соль одинаковым движением.

сысала сыса́ла суса́ла "морда, рыло; скула", сиб. (Даль).  Связано, по-видимому, со звукоподражательными словами, приводимыми на су́слик, цслав. сысати "шипеть, свистеть", болг. съ́скам "шиплю", д.-в.-н. sûsôn, sûsan "жужжать", шв. susа – то же. Едва ли можно говорить об и.-е. древности, судя по сохранению s после u в слав.; см. Торп 446; Траутман, ВSW 294; Шарпантье, IF 25, 250. Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973

Сусальное золото-на вид сальное, блестит, да и на ощупь скользкое и лоснится когда прилипнет. На масло похоже, и на старое желтое сало. 
И что интересно и сало и золото произошли от соли, первое: всегда солили подкожный жир, чтоб не портился, как и мясо-солонину. А соль--самый первый товар и деньги, впоследствии замененный металлом и соль осталась  в несколько измененном корне.